# Не работает Пагинатор в админ панели

Tags: php

Пару дней назад всё работало отлично а теперь не работает переключение страниц.
что могло произойти ,подскажите.
Это отрывок кода:

```
// check page parameter
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    }else{
        $page = 1;
    }

    // number of data that will be display per page     
    $offset = 10;

    //lets calculate the LIMIT for SQL, and save it $from
    if ($page){
        $from   = ($page * $offset) - $offset;
    }else{
        //if nothing was given in page request, lets load the first page
        $from = 0;  
    }
```

Comment: &keyword= это параметр который Вы вводите в Поиск по названию

Comment: и совет вам на будущее, не ставьте в админ панели логин и пароль admin admin, я вот сейчас нахожусь в вашей админке и кстате пагинация у меня работает

Comment: @madfan41k -Спасибо за совет. Я только начинаю изучать программирование.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт ,разобрался .
Проблема была в :

```
`include_once('functions.php'); `
```